# cpprestsdk Segmentation Fault in http_request::set_body on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, cpprest-sdk

I try to send a HTTP (REST) request to a server with `cpprestsdk`.

```
void postRestRequest(const std::string& uri, const std::string& requestJson) {
  const std::string host = "localhost:8080";
  const http_client_config authorization = setupAuthorization();

  http_client client(U(host), authorization);
  http_request request(methods::POST);
  uri_builder builder(U(uri));
  request.set_request_uri(builder.to_string());

  if (not requestJson.empty()) {
    const auto mimeType = utf8string("application/json; charset=utf-8");
    request.set_body(requestJson, mimeType); // SEGFAULT here
  }
}
```

The call stack is:

```
-|libpthread.so.0
-|[1]
-|
-|libcpprest.so.2.9
-|[2]    : pplx::task_completion_event<unsigned long>::set(unsigned long) const+0xb4
-|
-|mylib.so
-|[3]    : postRestRequest(std::string const&, std::string const&)+0x49a
```

I'm not sure if I use the library as expected.
I don't know exactly how the tasks in the `pplx` library work.

Could it also be a bug in the cpprestsdk library.
But creating HTTP requests is an essential part of a REST framework. So I can't imagine that there is a unknown bug in the librrary.

Linux: RHEL7
cpprestsdk: 2.9
gcc: 6.3.1

Comment: How did you create `requestJson`?
You should build a `web::json::value` with your request. Then you parameterize `request.set_body()` with the serialized `web::json::value`.

Comment: We use a different JSON library. So I provide it as a std::string

Comment: Following the information on https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/issues/72 I'd say you need to work with std::wstring.

Comment: I changed the code to use a `json::value` object instead of a `std::string`: `auto jsonValue = web::json::value::parse(requestJson);
request.set_body(jsonValue); // still segfault here`

Comment: Did you check whether the parsing was successful? Does `web::json::value::serialize()` return you something equal to what you put into `web::json::value::parse()`?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use a `web::json::value`. Note that I use member functions like `value::number` to create valid json values for my request object.

```
web::json::value requestParameters;
requestParameters[U("foo")] = web::json::value::number(1);
requestParameters[U("bar")] = web::json::value::string(U("whatever"));

utility::stringstream_t paramStream;
requestParameters.serialize(paramStream);

web::http::http_request request(web::http::methods::POST);
request.set_request_uri(U("MethodName"));
request.set_body(paramStream.str());
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem how the library was built (as RPM).
Now it works.